Incorrect API key provided: ***. You can find your API key at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys
I am trying to connect my telegram bot with OpenAI and get an error message: "Invalid API key provided: sk -***. You can find your API key at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys ". Checked 5 times, I'm sure, that API_key is OK. Are there any other errors leading to this?
Checked api_key, there are no extra spaces for sure. I also changed the OpenAI version from 1.35 to 0.28. Noticed that if the key is used immediately after re-generation, it works. Used two ways to request OpenAI, through requests and OpenAI itself:
First one, openai version is 0.28
async def ask_gpt(question):
    openai.api_key = gpt_config['api_key']
    message = [
        {'role': 'system', 'content': 'You are an assistant'},
        {'role': 'user', 'content': question}
        ]

    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model=gpt_config['model']
        , messages=message
        , temperature=gpt_config['temperature']
    )

    return response.choices[0].message['content']

Second one,
async def ask_gpt(question):
   headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}',
   }


   data = {
      'model': gpt_config['model'],
      'prompt': question,
      'max_tokens': gpt_config['max_tokens'],
      'temperature': gpt_config['temperature']
   }

   response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

   if response.status_code == 200:
      response_data = response.json()
      generated_text = response_data['choices'][0]['text']
      print('Answer is:', generated_text)
   else:
      print(f'Something went wrong, {response.status_code}')
      print(response.text)

